# Using a foreach loop to grab data and send an email through a cron job

Tags: php, database, email, cron

I have a php file that uses php mail to send an email. I have a foreach loop set up to pull data from a table and send an email for each row. I am able to write the email and then echo it to verify that it looks correct and pulls the correct data. The issue I am having is that when I create the cron job (in cpanel) it sends back a 500 internal server error. If I take away all database connections from the file then it works properly so I know the cron job is set up correctly.

This is my php file:

```
<?php
include('config/route.php');

$agent = "SELECT * FROM the_agent WHERE status = 1";
$agentInfo = $obj->queryResult($agent);

        foreach($agentInfo as $value){
        $to      = 'my email';
        $subject = 'Your Match Request';
        $message = "<p>Hey ".$value['name']."!</p>
                    <p>Here is your weekly report.</p>
                    <p>You had ____ full job description/profile views from the following travelers: </p>
                    <p>(List of Travelers first names and disciplines)</p>
                    <p>And ____ applications from: </p>
                    <p>(List of travelers full names and disciplines)</p>
                    <p>This weeks matches include: </p>
                    <p>(List of matches)</p>
                    <p>I hope you had a great week! Don't forget to follow up with your applicants today if you haven't done so already.</p>
                    <p>Have an awesome weekend!</p>
                    ";
                
        $headers = array(
                    'From: email',
                    'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'
                    );
    

    
        mail($to, $subject, $message,implode("\r\n",$headers));

        }



?>
```

Is there something I am missing/doing wrong in my php file? Is there something I am unaware of with cron jobs and database connections? This is my first time dealing with cron jobs so any input or advice would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your code relies on an environmental variable to set up the database connection that's not available in cron jobs.

$ export

displays your current environmental variables

Difficult to suggest for sure what's needed without knowing your database, but you should be able to do something like this at the top of your cron file to populate an environmental variable:

ORACLE_SID=testdb
0 7 * * * php emailscript.php